# C++ vectors of values returning a matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have 4 integer variables - x,y,z,t which could get values from an interval of integer values [a,b] ) ( the interval is a,a+1,a+2,...,b ).

I want to set a vector of distinct {x,y,z,t} values with the following rule:

2 quartets (x and y) are not equal if there exists at least one quartet value for which : x.i != y.i (i is one of the {x,y,z,t} value positions).

My current solution is extremely time consuming:

```
struct gim
{
    int xx;
    int yy;
    int zz;
    int tt;
}
vector<gim> v;
x=a;y=a;z=a;t=a;
nr_quartet=0;
gim g;
while(x<=b)
{
    while(y<=b)
    {
        while(z<=b)
        {
            while(t<=b)
            {
                if(at least one of x,y,z,t is different)
                {
                    nr_quartet++;
                    g.xx=x;
                    g.yy=y;
                    g.zz=z;
                    g.tt=t;
                    v.push_back(g);
                    cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << " " << t << "\n";
                }
                t++;
            }
            z++;
        }
        y++;
    }
    x++;
}
```

Comment: And you want a faster method? I suspect that the `cout ...` is the most time-consuming part of this process, and there is no way to accelerate it. But it will scroll by faster than the eye can read it, so why do you want it to be faster?

Comment: Due to while imbrication, your algorithm is of complexity O(n^4). You need it to be less exponential, at least of complexity O(n) or O(nlogn).

Comment: I know it is of complexity O(n^4). That's why I want to implement another method. But I don't know how to catch this.

Comment: Another point, you can perform std::vector population like this v.emplace_back(x,y,z,t) directly without using a temporary object gim that need a copy. emplace_back uses placement-new to construct the element in-place at the location provided by the container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
int actual_t = t;
int actual_z = z;
int actual_y = y;
int actual_x = x;
while(t<=b && z <=b && y<=b && x<=b)
{
    if(at least one of x,y,z,t is different)
    {
        nr_quartet++;
        v.emplace_back(x, y, z, t);
        //cout << x << " " << y << " " << z << " " << t << "\n";
    }
    // For t
    if(t==b)
    {
        t = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        t++;
    }
    actual_t = t;

    // For z
    if(z==b)
    {
        z = 0;
    }
    else if(/* incrementation condition for z */)
    {
        z++;
    }
    actual_z = z;

    /* the same for y and x */
}
```

Comment: Maybe if (t==b) t=a else t++. That's to begin from the beginning of the range [a,b]. That's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the number of elements of the set `{(x,y,z,t) | ¬(x = y = z = t)}`, then compute `(b-a)**4 - (b-a)`; i.e. no need to iterate through all of them.

If you really need to fill a `vector` with all the combinations, well, you will have to iterate to add them all. The longest part will be memory allocations inside the `std::vector`, so pre-[`reserve`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) or pre-[`resize`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) with the number of elements since you can know it in advance.

> As far as I've done is something which is consuming much time

What do you mean it is consuming a lot of time? What is your `[a, b]` range?

Comment: I need a new method of iteration to populate my vector. The [a,b] range is -500≤a≤b≤500

Comment: And I need something to respect the rule of distinct quartets - if(at least one of x,y,z,t is different)

Comment: @sorineatza: I am not sure what you mean by "The [a,b] range is -500≤a≤b≤500" -- that is not the range, but the constraints on the start and end of the range. If you mean [a, b] = [-500, 500]; then you would have a trillion of elements and it would take roughly 14 TiB of memory using 32-bit integers.

Comment: You misunderstood. a and b could be in this range of values from -500 to 500. For example, you could have a range [-2,3] and the quartets would get the values from this range: -2,-1,0,1,2,3 but pay attention of my rule: what it means distinct quartets. That's why I need a new method. IMO, it should be an algorithm of queues or something else.

Comment: @sorineatza: No, I did not misunderstood. If your actual range (rather than the constraints on `a` and `b`) is something as short as [-2, 3], then your program should be nearly instantaneous. A range like [0, 80] should take your program less than a second.

Comment: Ignore the above comment, I write wrong. An example of how quartets are distinct is this: {-1,-1,0,-1},{0,-1,-1,0}, {0,-1,1,1},{0,0,-1,-1},{0,0,1,0},{0,1,1,-1},{1,0,0,1},{1,1,0,0} etc for interval [-1,1]. If you take any 2 quartets from the above list you will see they are distinct.